# WindowPhone FlipView System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, flipview

I have a problem with using FlipView in my WindowsPhone app. 
I have a Page with FlipView, which has ItemsSource that binds to ItemsGroup and SelectedItem that binds to CurrentItem. DataTemplate of FlipView includes WebView which has attached property Html that binds to Html of CurrentItem. Everything goes well, but the app crashes with System.ArgumentException from time to time and I have no idea what's wrong.

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="UkraineNews.ItemPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:common="using:News.Common"
xmlns:viewModel="using:News.ViewModel"
xmlns:converter="using:News.Converter">
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewModel:PhoneGroupViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Page.Resources>
    <converter:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter" 
                             IsShowFullDate="True"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Group.Items}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Group.CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Row="0" 
                            Background="{StaticResource ItemBorderBackground}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Padding="5"
                            CornerRadius="0,0,0,5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Published, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text="{Binding Title}"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Margin="24,0"
                               FontSize="20"
                               Foreground="{StaticResource LeftMenuBackgroundBrush}"/>
                    <WebView Grid.Row="2" 
                             NavigationStarting="WebView_NavigationStarting"
                             common:WebViewBehaviour.Html="{Binding Html}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
  public class NewsItem 
  {
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Link { get; set; }
     public DateTime Published { get; set; }
     public string Html { get; set; }
     public string Image { get; set; }
  }
```

Error:

> The parameter is incorrect. System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: I'm observing the same behavior. I think it is a bug in the flipview when items are added while the user is interacting with the control. Haven't been able to reproduce or locate the bug sadly.

Comment: It's look like problem is in 2.5 points margin in default template of FlipView, but I don't know how this related to this problem. I've removed them and the problem gone.

Comment: Can you expand upon your solution?

Comment: I've had a similar issue the last few days. However instead of height or margins, it seems the scale was the problem. Seems to be some issue when these things are changed on launch while assigning items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replaced default Templete for FlipView with my custom one, in which i remove 2.5 point margin of Border. I don't know how, but it works. Maybe it connected with the pointer that get onto margin area, because error took place when swipe from the edge.

```
<Style x:Key="FlipViewStyle" TargetType="FlipView">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel AreScrollSnapPointsRegular="True" 
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlipView">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollingHost" 
                                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                                          BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" 
                                          HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" 
                                          HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                          IsTabStop="False" 
                                          IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" 
                                          IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" 
                                          IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" 
                                          IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" 
                                          IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" 
                                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                          TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" 
                                          VerticalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" 
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                          VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" 
                                          ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```